# Dash output on webpage

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I've only ever used Python in jupyter notebooks.  I'm watching this video on Dash and his code outputs as a webpage. Where do I need to run my code to do that.

Here is the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSPmj7mK6ng&t=625s

Comment: just run the file?

Comment: What exatcly is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your main file is, let's call it `dash_app.py`, can be run from the command line like:

`python dash_app.py`

You need to have Python installed on the computer you're using, of course, and you should navigate to the directory that contains your file before running that command. Once it runs, there should be a message that the page is available at a certain address, and you can direct your browser there to see it running locally.

To run it on the internet, available for anyone to visit, is a completely different story, and requires a whole lot more technology and setup. I won't get into it further, because it goes way beyond the scope of a single question here.